# Proper Grammar of Degree Abbreviations

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, academic-writing

I have seen plenty of abbreviation options to write Postgraduate Diploma.

Just to mention the easiest finding on the web: "A postgraduate diploma (PgD, PgDip, PGDip, PG Dip., PGD, Dipl. PG, PDE) is a postgraduate qualification awarded after a university degree." (Wikipedia)

After checking multiple University pages and forums, I have discovered that the most frequent way of mentioning the Post Graduate Diploma in the U.S.A. is PGD (or PG Diploma); however I have never seen it written with dots (PG.D or something like this).

I find it strange because most of these abbreviations are written with dots in it in the U.S.A., e.g., B.Sc., M.Sc., Ph.D.

I know this is a very insignificant question but I want to write a document with consistency in it. I have already mentioned B.Sc. and M.Sc. multiple times in this doc.

Would someone be able to guide me on this? (The U.S. way of writing should be applied.)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Abbreviations are not matters of "grammar," only of convention, and as far as I know there is no governing body dictating a "right way." As you say, just be consistent. If you use "B.Sc.", then use "M.Sc".

Comment: Thank you, Andy. In this case, "P.G.D." should be good a good abbreviation for Postgraduate Diplomas.

Comment: Please get this straight: We don't say post-graduate like that in English. Post-graduate in American English **means** after you have done every level of degree. The levels in American English are: **undergraduate degree** (Bachelor of Science or Bachelor of Arts) and **graduate degrees** (Masters of Science, Master of Arts, and others AND Doctoral Degree or Ph.D, in [field]. This post-graduate thing is taken from Portuguese and does not apply in English, unless you say something like: post-doctoral fellowship.

Comment: [cont'd] And yes, all those undergraduate and graduate degrees are written with periods when written in short form. [I forgot MBA]. In Portuguese, "pós-graduado" is what we call in AmE: a graduate degree, Master's and/or then Ph.D. The term pós-graduado is a false friend. The correct translation of it is: a graduate degree.

Comment: @Lambie I'd check in a few dictionaries, and in spite of your AmE caveat, 'This post-graduate thing is taken from Portuguese and does not apply in English' needs qualifying. The term is normal in the UK for masters degrees and doctorates. And Etymon says that it derives from the constituents, first appearing in the US.

Comment: There is no such thing in the U.S. as a P.D.G., I can guarantee you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP wants to say: post-graduate degree with an abbreviation. That is not kosher in the US or the UK. It's **because** in Portuguese: pós-graduado **means** a graduate degree. And I explained that already. So please read my most more carefully! In my second post, I wrote: undergraduate and graduate degrees. It is not fun to say everything twice. The OP believes that a post-graduate degree is a single thing. S/he does not know it can be one of two things and is not a single degree.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications. So, to put it in a context, I am creating a document and use it for a USA application. I am trying to include that I have a "PgDip" from a country where it exists (UK) and I don't want to make up a degree or a word that does not exist. Also, I want to avoid using "PgDip" as it can cause confusion as that is not a thing in the US.

Comment: Why would you abbreviate "postgraduate diploma" in an application? Writing it out is certainly clearer.

Comment: You would not use an abbreviation. You state the degree. You still have not understood even after all this explanation. We do not say in applications: post-graduate degree. We say what it is we actually HAVE: In the UK, as in the USA, a post-graduate degree is a generic term, it is not the term for a diploma or degree. No one says that. You say: I have a Master's in Y, I have a Ph.d in Z., I have an MBA.

Comment: Don't need to be angry with me. I am trying to understand, not refusing to understand. I am terribly sorry for this. Anyway, as Laurel suggested, I am going to write it out: "I have a postgraduate diploma in in Economics”. This is a diploma rewarded at the end of a postgraduate specialisation programme. I might include the ISCED level to grant better understanding for the reader. I want to thank you again for your contribution to my knowledge, I appreciate it.